# Upgrade project from WorkLight 6.1 to MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, mobilefirst-server

I have a project build with WorkLight 6.1 and I'm going to upgrade this project to MobileFirst 7.1 . 
I found a link from IBM regrading [upgrade from earlier version of MobileFirst](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/t_upgrade_studio.html?lang=en) , but not from WorkLight 6.1 .

Appreciate if anyone can provide me the guidelines to upgrade WorkLight Studio & Server 6.1 to MobileFirst Studio & Server 7.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open MobileFirst Studio 7.1
2. Select File -> Import > Existing projects into worksace
3. Select your project (make sure to make a backup)

Let Studio upgrade your project

Answer (score 2):

Complete instructions for upgrading your server from 6.1 to 7.1 can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_in_production_env.html)

The most complicated part of the process involves upgrading your databases (to reflect changes in the database schema and the data that is stored) - this must be done in 4 separate steps.  You must first upgrade the databases from 6.1 to 6.2, then from 6.2 to 6.3, then 6.3 to 7.0, and finally 7.0 to 7.1.  There are scripts provided for each of these steps, which must be done in that specific order.  There are some additional manual steps that must be done if you use push notification in your app.

All of the steps are described in detail in the document linked above.